# function as parameter of a filter in django

Tags: python, django, filter

could someone take a doubt about filter using django, I have a class and in this class I have a function, and I wanted to pass this function as a parameter inside a filter in django, would it be possible?

```
#model
class Bens(models.Model):
    identificador = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True) # Série/Chassi
    codigo = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def dentrorev(self): 
        ultimo_uso = Usos.objects.filter(bem=self.codigo).order_by('-data').first()
        margem_atual = ultimo_uso.valor%self.periodoRevisao

        if(margem_atual>=(self.periodoRevisao-self.margemRevisao) and margem_atual <=(self.periodoRevisao) or margem_atual>=0 and margem_atual<=(self.margemRevisao)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def forarev(self):

        bensUsos = Bens.objects.filter(codigo__in = [x['ordemServico__uso__bem__codigo'] for x in OrdensServicos.objects.exclude(listaStatus='4').order_by('ordemServico__uso__bem__codigo').values('ordemServico__uso__bem').distinct().values('ordemServico__uso__bem__codigo')])

        if self.codigo in bensUsos:
            return False
        else:
            return True

#view
revisao = Bens.objects.filter(dentrorev=True).union(Bens.objects.filter(forarev=True))
```

Comment: Perhaps if you turn the function into a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did face a very similar situation and I could't solve it neither with calculated fields (like you) nor with `annotate`. My solution was:

1. Create new "real" fields in the table ('dentrorev' & `forarev' in your case).
2. put those functions in the view (or call them from the view in my case) and modify them to iterate through the dataset and write the calculated values to the DB.

If you think it carefully, it is not very diferent in terms of performance, since the calculated field is doing the same except for writing to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

No, Django ORM operates at the database level - you would have to fetch an instance first to evaluate the method. You can write a custom Manager for your Model class for some workaround, but it is hard to provide an example when the code is not written in English.